# Syntax error in SQL create table command

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an Syntax error in my SQL create table command but cant understand why?

```
CREATE TABLE E0 (
    div VARCHAR(50),
    date VARCHAR(50), hometeam VARCHAR(50), awayteam VARCHAR(50),
    fthg VARCHAR(50), ftag VARCHAR(50), ftr VARCHAR(50),
    hthg VARCHAR(50), htag VARCHAR(50), htr VARCHAR(50),
    referee VARCHAR(50), hs VARCHAR(50),
    as VARCHAR(50),
    hst VARCHAR(50), ast VARCHAR(50), hf VARCHAR(50),
    af VARCHAR(50), hc VARCHAR(50), ac VARCHAR(50),
    hy VARCHAR(50), ay VARCHAR(50), hr VARCHAR(50),
    ar VARCHAR(50), b365h VARCHAR(50), b365d VARCHAR(50),
    b365a VARCHAR(50), bwh VARCHAR(50), bwd VARCHAR(50),
    bwa VARCHAR(50), iwh VARCHAR(50), iwd VARCHAR(50),
    iwa VARCHAR(50), lbh VARCHAR(50), lbd VARCHAR(50),
    lba VARCHAR(50), psh VARCHAR(50), psd VARCHAR(50),
    psa VARCHAR(50), whh VARCHAR(50), whd VARCHAR(50),
    wha VARCHAR(50), vch VARCHAR(50), vcd VARCHAR(50),
    vca VARCHAR(50), bb1x2 VARCHAR(50), bbmxh VARCHAR(50),
    bbavh VARCHAR(50), bbmxd VARCHAR(50), bbavd VARCHAR(50), bbmxa VARCHAR(50), bbava VARCHAR(50), bbou VARCHAR(50), bbmx_2_5 VARCHAR(50), bbav_2_5 VARCHAR(50), bbmx_2_5 VARCHAR(50), bbav_2_5 VARCHAR(50), bbah VARCHAR(50), bbahh VARCHAR(50), bbmxahh VARCHAR(50), bbavahh VARCHAR(50), bbmxaha VARCHAR(50), bbavaha VARCHAR(50))
```

Comment: At least in ANSI SQL `date` is a reserved word and needs to be delimited as `"date"`, or in the MySQL case using back-ticks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`as`, `div` and `date` are sql reserved words (see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)), you cannot have such names without escaping with backticks.

Comment: `date` is not a reserved word, it's a keyword.

Answer (score 2):

One of the columns is named AS which is a reserved word. Either use different name or wrap around `` like `as` varchar(50)

Answer (score 1):

1)`Div and AS` are [mysql reserved key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) it must be in backtick

2) Duplicate column `bbmx_2_5` and `bbav_2_5` remove

Whole query would be

```
CREATE TABLE E0 (`div` VARCHAR(50), date VARCHAR(50), hometeam VARCHAR(50), awayteam VARCHAR(50), fthg VARCHAR(50), ftag VARCHAR(50), ftr VARCHAR(50), hthg VARCHAR(50), htag VARCHAR(50), htr VARCHAR(50), referee VARCHAR(50), hs VARCHAR(50), `as` VARCHAR(50), hst VARCHAR(50), ast VARCHAR(50), hf VARCHAR(50), af VARCHAR(50), hc VARCHAR(50), ac VARCHAR(50), hy VARCHAR(50), ay VARCHAR(50), hr VARCHAR(50), ar VARCHAR(50), b365h VARCHAR(50), b365d VARCHAR(50), b365a VARCHAR(50), bwh VARCHAR(50), bwd VARCHAR(50), bwa VARCHAR(50), iwh VARCHAR(50), iwd VARCHAR(50), iwa VARCHAR(50), lbh VARCHAR(50), lbd VARCHAR(50), lba VARCHAR(50), psh VARCHAR(50), psd VARCHAR(50), psa VARCHAR(50), whh VARCHAR(50), whd VARCHAR(50), wha VARCHAR(50), vch VARCHAR(50), vcd VARCHAR(50), vca VARCHAR(50), bb1x2 VARCHAR(50), bbmxh VARCHAR(50), bbavh VARCHAR(50), bbmxd VARCHAR(50), bbavd VARCHAR(50), bbmxa VARCHAR(50), bbava VARCHAR(50), bbou VARCHAR(50), bbmx_2_5 VARCHAR(50), bbav_2_5 VARCHAR(50), bbah VARCHAR(50), bbahh VARCHAR(50), bbmxahh VARCHAR(50), bbavahh VARCHAR(50), bbmxaha VARCHAR(50), bbavaha VARCHAR(50))
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your columns, `as`, is a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

Answer (score 0):

Lot of issues:

- DATE and DIV are [keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html); use `div` and `date` with backticks `.
- column name AS is not allowed after `hs VARCHAR(50)`, reserved keyword
- Duplicate columns `bbmx_2_5` and `bbav_2_5`

Comment: date is not a reserved word, it's a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has some keywords [reserved](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).

We cannot use them as database/table/field name.

There are two ways to overcome this problem:

1) Adding a backtick.

2) Prepending parent name.

e.g. `databasename.tablename`

OR

```
table.fieldName
```

But, the best way is to avoid using reserved keywords.

If your field name is `div`, you can rename it to `division`, if

your field name is `date`, you can rename it as `created_date`.